# Inexplicable gap in a bootstrap row/column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to code a simple gallery in Bootstrap, however, there is an unnecessary gap that keeps on appearing again and again on the right side of the column. I am unable to understand the cause of this gap.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="row" id="r2">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="heading">
            <h1>| PROJECTS |</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">   
            <img src="img/9.jpg" style='width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 left">  
            <img src="img/10.jpg" style='width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>                 
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 left">  
            <img src="img/11.jpg" style='width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 left">  
            <img src="img/8.jpg" style='width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 left">  
            <img src="img/7.jpg" style='width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 left">  
            <img src="img/8.jpg" style='width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">View More..</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>                    
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the webpage showing the gap:[Right Side Gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz24a.jpg)

The CSS Code :

```
.overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .overlay:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
    #r2{
        background:#2952a3;
        margin:0;
        }
```

Any sort of help would be really appreciated!

Comment: are you using container before row ? i don't see it ... and are you sure it's V4 of bootstrap ? it seems the V3

Comment: @Craig it's bootstrap

Comment: @Temani My bad.

Comment: Post your **complete** code snippet so that we can see what's actually going on. The current snippet is incomplete.

Comment: The snippet you post here needs to include all of your custom css (that you might have applied) as well all of the surrounding HTML.

Comment: @WebDevBooster : added the css and the remaining html code.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma So, are you actually using Bootstrap 3? If yes, why then have you added the Bootstrap 4 tag? Bootstrap 4 is completely different from Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @WebDevBooster : My bad ...edited the tag